# Larvel 7 reCaptcha - Service provider not found?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to implement invisible recaptcha but it throws an error and I've been stuck for 2 days now...

I'm using albertcht/invisible-recaptcha.

What am I doing wrong?

```
1. I've downloaded the package:

   composer require albertcht/invisible-recaptcha

2. I've added this into service providers (app.php):

   AlbertCht\InvisibleReCaptcha\InvisibleReCaptchaServiceProvider::class,
```

When I try to visit the page, this error comes up: Class 'AlbertCht\InvisibleReCaptcha\InvisibleReCaptchaServiceProvider' not found

I've tried composer dump-autoload but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May be this is not suitable for 7.x, even 6.x. you can try this one https://github.com/biscolab/laravel-recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

There could be a compatibility issue maybe you can run following command,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I would like you to check around with [this](https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha) package, I have integrated this in 3 sites and its very easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

> add
> AlbertCht\InvisibleReCaptcha\InvisibleReCaptchaServiceProvider::class into correct providers array in app/config/app.php

```
composer dump-autoload

composer install

Php artisan config:cache
```